# Luis choosing between two intent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

If the luis highest intent score for a conversation is 0.15, and the second is 0.14, would it be possible for the bot to ask the user if they meant the first intent or the second intent? If yes how to do so? I've been searching in the documentation samples and there doesn't seem to be any solution except just making more and more utterances so this does not happen; is that correct?

Comment: `the luis highest intent score for a conversation is 0.15, and the second is 0.14` Could you share the details of the intents and entities that you defined and created in your LUIS app?

Comment: there's too many intent in my LUIS app, but i think its because 3 of my intent is related to paying something (property, tax, library services) where the result are 0.11 and 0.09. While entities wise there's nothing on those 3 just an utterence. though is it even possible to make the bot re-ask the user ?

Comment: Hi @user3646742, I create a sample to achieve your requirement, please refer to my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the luis highest intent score for a conversation is 0.15, and the second is 0.14, would it be possible for the bot to ask the user if they meant the first intent or the second intent? If yes how to do so?

Yes, we can achieve this requirement. The following sample code work for me, you can refer to it.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public MyLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute("xxxxxxx", 
        "xxxxxxx", 
        domain: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")))
    {
    }


    //modify Luis request to make it return all intents instead of just the topscoring intent
    protected override LuisRequest ModifyLuisRequest(LuisRequest request)
    {
        request.Verbose = true;
        return request;
    }

    protected override async Task DispatchToIntentHandler(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item, IntentRecommendation bestIntent, LuisResult result)
    {

        if (bestIntent.Intent == "FindFood" || bestIntent.Intent == "BuyFood")
        {
            if (result.Intents[0].Score - result.Intents[1].Score < 0.1)
            {
                bestIntent.Intent = "FindOrBuyFood";
                bestIntent.Score = 1;
            }
        }

        await base.DispatchToIntentHandler(context, item, bestIntent, result);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
    public async Task GreetingIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    //...
    //other intent handlers
    //...

    [LuisIntent("FindFood")]
    [LuisIntent("BuyFood")]
    public async Task FoodIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    [LuisIntent("FindOrBuyFood")]
    public async Task FindOrBuyFoodIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var food = "food";

        if (result.Entities.Count() > 0)
        {
            food = result.Entities[0].Entity;
        }

        List<string> options = new List<string>() { $"Find {food}", $"Buy {food}" };

        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context,
            resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
            options: options,
            prompt: "Hi. Please Select one option :",
            retry: "Please try again.",
            promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
            );
    }

    private async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var option = await result;

        //your code logic here

        await context.PostAsync($"You selected the '{option}'");

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent} intent.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
```

***Test Result:***

[image]