# Is it possible for users to choose between a few intents for Bot Framework Composer (LUIS)?

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to get something like this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664161/luis-choosing-between-two-intent) but within Bot Framework Composer. In Power Virtual Agents, if the bot is not sure about which 'Topic' aka 'Intent' is the right one, it gives the user a few options. How can I achieve that in Bot Framework Composer, or at least extend the bot with code?

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog, create a trigger for "Duplicated intents recognized" :

[image]

Duplicated intents recognized automatically sets some variables for the turn that you use to customize your logic in how to handle duplicate intent recognition.
From here I refer to the Enterprise Assistant template :

[image]

> conversation.lastAmbiguousUtterance = turn.activity.text
> You don't really need to use this, but it's set in the Enterprise template in case you want to use the user input in the bot's response

> dialog.candidates =
>
> =take(sortByDescending(where(flatten(select(turn.recognized.candidates,
> x, if (x.intent=="ChooseIntent", x.result.candidates, x))), c,
> not(startsWith(c.intent, "DeferToRecognizer_QnA")) && c.score >
> turn.minThreshold), 'score'), turn.maxChoices)

This basically organizes the duplicate intents into a list, dialog.candidates, by

1. sorting the intent recognized in descending order (so first element is the highest recognition score intent)
2. filtering out intents starting with "DeferToRecognizer_QnA" that are automatically generated from cross-training
3. filtering out intent scores that don't meet the minimum threshold that you set
4. getting only the number of intents for max choices that you set

From here you can set your logic so that if

> count(dialog.candidates) = 0

, you emit an UnknownIntent event, or emit a recognizedIntent for

> =first(dialog.candidates).result

if your dialog.candidates has at least one result.

Or, you can customize your logic to handle however which way you want, which in your case is inputting dialog.candidates in an adaptive card so the user can choose which intent they wanted.